# ChartJS Annotations display custom label

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

is there any way to display a custom label on mouse hover chartJS annotations like it displayed on ChartJS?
For example, when you create a line chart of points, and you hover one of the points, it displays the label of that point.
I want something similar to that but on annotation.

Answer (score 1):

onHover API

```
  options: {
    // LOOK AT ME!!! I'M SO IMPORTANT!!!
    onHover: function onHover (evt, activeElements) {
      if (!activeElements || !activeElements.length) return;
      // logic operation
      this.update();
    },


  },
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html